# nginx rewrite error, invalid number of arguments

Tags: nginx, rewrite, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm running nginx 1.13.6. The configuration has this directive to serve a virtual host `service.company.com/` using `service.company.com/svc/`:

```
if ($server_name = service.company.com) {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /svc/$1 last;
}
```

The server starts successfully, albeit with an entry in `error.log`:

> [emerg] 60841#0: invalid number of arguments in "rewrite" directive in …

Oddly, the line number in the error is the last line of the configuration file. The error is consistent with a missing semicolon. But, there's a semicolon there. And everything works fine except that the rewrite rule is ignored.

Does this seemingly trivial command have a syntax error?

Is there a better approach to the original problem?

Comment: You could try `nginx -T` to see exactly which files `nginx` is processing.

Comment: @RichardSmith Nothing interesting there. Also `nginx -t` specifically says `syntax is ok`.